# Display pictures stored as bytea in postgresql column in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgresql

does someone knows a possibility to visualize in a bytea column saved photos of a postgresql database in qgis?

I would like to store pictures directly into the database, not just the link/ url.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Try looking into LOB https://giswiki.hsr.ch/PostgreSQL_-_Binary_Large_Objects

Comment: I'm asking myself this question too

Answer (score 1):

It isn't directly possible in QGIS. Easiest approach would be to pass the bytea off to a web page/API that just presents the photo. 
Then you can create a View in PostGIS, and have a new column that has a URL pointing to the page: eg http://example.com/photo.php?id=1234, you can load the view into QGIS.